# Get input checked values like it was a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have a group of inputs:

```
 <input type=checkbox value=1 checked/>
 <input type=checkbox value=2 checked/>
 <input type=checkbox value=3 checked/>
 <input type=checkbox value=4 checked/>
```

`$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked").val();` doesn't work and even `$("input[type=checkbox]").val();` only returns the first one.  I know I could use `$.each()` but i'm possibly looking for a more efficient way. I would like it returned just like a normal form type value returned preferrably, like this: `1,2,3,4`

Ideas?

Comment: You can't get the values from all checkboxes at one time without iterating over them no matter if you use each, map, or simple loop. A possible alternative could be to start with empty array and unchecked checkboxes, attach click/change event on every checkbox and add/remove the checked/unchecked value but imo it's more complicated. Just use each, map, loop .. :)

Comment: `.is()` returns a boolean, not a jQuery object. You can't apply jQuery methods to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.map()` along with `.get()` to collect the checked checkbox values in an array,

```
var values = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value; 
}).get(); // 1,2,3,4  But the values would be in an array
```

If you want those values as a joined string then do,

```
var result = values.join(); //"1,2,3,4"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

> Description: Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return value.
>
> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array.

Use

```
var arr = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value; // $(this).val()
}).get(); //Result in array
var values = arr.join(); in string
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not friendly with jQuery, so I have no-Jquery solution (read no-jQuery as fast). My solution is slightly longer, but is very fast. In jsperf 29 times faster as opponent's solution. http://jsperf.com/map-vs-cycle
It is overhead cost of jQuery map method.

Here's code:

```
var chckbxs =  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"), // NodeList with these checkboxes
    num = chckbxs.length,
    values = [], i
for(i = 0; i < num; i++) // save values into array
  values[i] = chckbxs[i].value;
values = values.toString() // to string data
```